# Python: optimizing mesh animation

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

So I am working on an addon which will help to make procedural animation. Up to now, I am implementing the possibility to animation a mesh's polygons using a reference animated object.

Here is an example:

[image: procedural mesh animation]

**The basic process is the next one:**

On each frame and on each polygon:
I get the data of the animated reference at the required frame(depending of the falloff options) and I apply the transformation to the polygon's vertices.

The problem is that when I do this on huge meshes, it's very slow and **blender crash during the render** (memory issue I guess).

I would like to know if there is some possibilities regarding dynamic mesh with python. Also, it would have been nice to make it in C++ but there isn't any API (tell me if I'm wrong). And in the future, I would like to use this tool for other type of data like groups, arrays, texts. I guess I have no choice than using python.

Here is the blend file of the example. https://framadrop.org/r/lE61zHEGMX#An6enLpjxdsw4uILLdbtwRbiTIXr1+TIoO62fAIEaoo=

Comment: Just curious, how is this different/better than Animation Nodes?

Comment: It would be dedicated to this and only this. You won't have to worry with visual programming and setting up your nodes. Moreover, if you want to change the parameters (falloff, the way the animation is applied, axis of direction, thickness) would be easier. I could have done some presets for AN but I think there is a few things I won't be able to do.

Comment: I will try to do the same setup on the same mesh with AN to see if it crashes.

Comment: you should use the foreach_set function for faster update of the mesh.  Also there is are Mesh.update and Mesh.validate functions. Both slow down performance quite a bit. Calling Mesh.validate() will makes sure that the mesh you created is in a correct state. (I have not looked at the file yet)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look. I am not using either one of these functions. I think the problem is that the mesh is stored in memory at each frame so up to a certain point, it explodes.. foreach_set is from the python api or from AN ?

Comment: the foreach_set method is from the blender Python api. you can also look at the source code of the Mesh.from_pydata function. And you definitly should not create a new mesh object on every frame. Instead you can reuse an existing one.

Comment: I don't recreate a new mesh on each frame, this is why I'm confused about the time it takes :/

Comment: @JacquesLucke can I have you opinion on this addon ? Do you think it's relevant or there is no need at all to make it ?

Comment: Well it is always good to see different approaches to this problem, so I support everyone how does it. Not sure what you exact goal with this is but there is also the new Animax addon in the Blendermarket which does similar things.

Comment: Oh dear, that's exactly the tool I had in mind.. but in free. Thank you for the feedback, now I don't know if it's worth it anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58805/discussion-between-kevin-m-and-jacques-lucke).